# A block in understanding a proof of Sylow's Theorem

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

If $G$ is a finite group of order $n$ and $p$ is a prime divisor $|G|$, then according to one of Sylow's theorems $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^m$, where $p^m$ is the *highest* power of $p$ which is a factor of $|G|$.

Here is a rough outline of the proof I am trying to understand. Let $|G|=k\cdot p^m$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z^+}$.

The proof begins by defining the set $X=\{A \subseteq G:|A|=p^m\}$ and the action of $G$ on $X$ by left translation, $G \times X \rightarrow X:(g,A)\mapsto gA$. The size of $X$ is the binomial coefficient ${k \cdot p^m}\choose {p^m}$. Here is where I lose the line of argument:

(1) the size of $X$ is not divisible by $p$, and (as a result)...

(2) ... there must be an orbit $G(A)$ whose size is not a multiple of $p$.

Any clarification as to why this is the case?

Comment: @Dietrich Brude I am not asking for the full proof to Sylow's theorem here, but a clairification of two steps involved in the one I am trying to understand. I looked at the "answer" you suggested but it does not answer my questions.

Comment: It does answer your questions. It is explained that the binomial coeficient $\binom{kp^m}{p^m}$ is congruent $k\bmod p$, and that we have assumed $p\nmid k$ in the beginning. So $(1)$ is shown. Similarly with $(2)$.

Comment: One of the advantages of this proof (due to Wielandt) is that you do not need to assume that $p^m$ is the highest power of $p$ dividing $|G|$. It can be any such power.

Answer (score 2):

The orbits are disjoint and their union equals $X$, so if all their sizes were multiples of $p$ the size of $X$ would be a multiple of $p$.

We also have to show $|X|$ is not a multiple of $p$. We will show if $n$ is coprime to $p$ then $p\nmid{{p^{m}n}\choose{p^m}}$.

Define $v(k)=\max_{j}p^{j}\vert k$. Then:

$v(k\ell)=v(k)+v(\ell)$. Now just look at $v({{p^{m}n}\choose{p^m}})$. It equals:

$v(p^{m}n\cdot (p^{m}n-1))\cdot\ldots\cdot (p^{m}n-p^{m}+1)) - v(p^{m}!)$

and counting the numer of times p divides each term we want to show this is $0$. That's not so difficult: $p^{j}\vert (p^{m}n-k)$ (given n,p coprime, $k<p^{m}$) iff $p^{j}\vert (p^{m}-k)$. In fact you need $p^{j}\vert k$ for both conditions if $j\le m$ (and otherwise divisibility will not occur).

edited to answer part 1 of the original question.

Comment: Thank you. Answers my second question but why is $X$ not a multiple of $p^m$ then?

Comment: Added explanation.